# Playn Android port on real device

Tags: playn

I'm developing a game on playn and I'm having some problems to create an Android Port.

When I install the .apk on my tablet and try to open it, just show a message saying that the application was forced do close.

So I've installed the aLogcat app on the device to see what's going on and figured out the following exception:

"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match confgiSpec
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceViewBaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:760)"

This happen on a real device not on the emulator, and my tablet is running android 2.2 Froyo and it's support OpenGL, so I don't know what is wrong.

PS.: I tried an android market game that was built on playn and got the same error
http://www.tikalk.com/java/writing-real-games-android-using-playn

If anyone has any idea about this problem would be very hellpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of research on the web I realize that the problem was my tablet, because it don't support OpenGL ES 2, and that's a minimum requirement for playn to work.